# Limit one container per image

Tags: docker

I have to deploy my product on a client's server. I will provide my client with a docker image.

- I want to restrict clients to only start one container from an image on any machine. (If a container is started on one machine, another container shouldn't be able to start on any another machine or same machine)

To protect the code inside the container I decided to obfuscate the code. Is there a better and more secure solution?

Comment: Docker has no features to help with either task.  Anyone who has a Docker image can easily inspect its content, and you generally need root-level access to a system to run a `docker` command at all.  Whatever licensing system you'd use without Docker should also work inside a container.

Comment: This isn't a docker question, and containers are typically designed for the exact opposite purpose, to run multiple instances of the application horizontally scaled. The image is essentially a tar file of your application, so they can easily copy that to multiple hosts. Few people are even trying to enforce licenses on software like this now, and most users will opt for competing solutions that are easier to deploy.